# how to scroll text area horizontally?

Tags: jquery, css

How to scroll text area horizontally? I googled for it but could not find a good solution.

I tried the following css, but it is not working.

```
overflow-x: scroll;

<textarea></textarea>
```

Comment: You Googled it? https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=scroll+horizontally+css&oq=scroll+horizontally+css&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.11437j0j7&sourceid=chrome&espvd=210&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add the below lines to your CSS:

```
white-space: nowrap; /* will prevent the default wrapping of text to next line */
overflow-x: auto; /* will make horizontal scroll-bar appear only when needed */
```

[**Demo Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/hari_shanx/GGcqE/)

Comment: can you please give me a demo

Comment: @user2075328: Ah, I am not much familiar with Android development mate. It should have worked, but don't know :(

Comment: but i am using phone gap to develop android application here i am using html text box so this is not working for that if you know other approach than please tell me.

Comment: Something to keep in mind is that if you wish to see new lines properly, you must use `white-space: pre;`.

Answer (score 3):

The problem with `white-space: nowrap` is that intentional newlines (`\n`) will stop working too.

A better solution, that a least works in last Chrome is

```
white-space: pre;
```

which prevents line wrap (allows horizontal scroll) but the `\n` will keep working

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
textarea {
   overflow-x: vertical;
}
```

Comment: I need text scroll horizontally not vertically

Answer (score 0):

You're doing it a bit wrong.

```
overflow-x: scroll;
```

Will create a scroll bar inside the textarea to scroll when text height is above the limit.

For this, the CSS clause is:

```
resize: vertical;
```

This will let the user resize the element vertically.

Comment: i am using phone gap to develop android application here i am using html text box so this is not working for that if you know other approach than please tell me.